# How to draw shapes with high performance on qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to develop a desktop application with QML. The app provides some drawing functions such as draw lines, rectangles, ellipses and so on. I find there are two ways to implement:

1. Inherit from `QQuickPaintedItem` and reimplement `void Quick::paint(QPainter *painter)`.
2. Draw shapes in `Canvas.onPaint` directly.

But I find both of the implementation are not as faster as `QWidget::paintEvent()`. From the [Qt Quick Scene Graph](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html) document says `QQuickPaintedItem` rendering is a two-step operation, and using **scene graph API** directly is always significantly faster. So how to use **scene graph API**
to implement that? Or I should use `QWidget` but not `QML`. Here is the [Sample code and performance effect](https://github.com/sfzhang/MyTest/tree/master/qml/painter).

Comment: You have to implement custom item derived from `QQuickItem` and implement your graphics inside [updatePaintNode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode) using SceneGraph API and OpenGL. There is no faster way in QML.

Comment: @folibis Could you show me a simple example such as **draw ellipse with mouse** in `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode`?

Comment: The simple example you can find in the Qt documentation provided by the link in my comment above. Also don't forget to set [QQuickItem::ItemHasContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#Flag-enum) otherwise you item will be 'non-visual'. I advice you to read [notes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#custom-scene-graph-items) how to implement custom item.

Comment: As a suggestion you can use OpenGL for drawing. But you must implement you class based on QQuickFramebufferObject. But it might be overkill for your task.

Comment: @folibis I inherit from `QQuickItem` and draw shape in `updatePaintNode` as the the [official demo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html). The performance is the same as the _implementation 1_. So I think it's because of the **qml** implementation that rendered by anther thread. And I still can't find a good way to draw different shapes (ellipse, polygon, ring..) with `QSGGeometry` in one `updatePaintNode` at the same time. Or should I implement different shapes as different `QQuickItem` subclass?

Comment: The first [link](https://github.com/cadet/UberQuick/blob/master/Items/Circle.cpp) from Google on query: "qsggeometry circle". I guess it could be helpful. As for performance I guess that QQuickItem is definitely faster, by definition. You should see that on a heavy graphics. As for different shapes in one item I guess that Barbara Liskov and [Single_responsibility_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) could explain it better.